# Arrays & JSON: Jquery $.each() only getting the last loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Here's what I need to do.

I need to create an array of array of objects like the format below. I am getting name and values of input boxes and put then in a json then push it in an array and then I push the generated array into another array.

```
[
    [
      {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},
      {"key1":"value3","key2":"value4"},
    ],

    [
      {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},
      {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},
    ]
]`
```

**below is my code**

```
$scope.saveImages = function(){
    var arrayOfArrays =[];
    var arrayOfPhotos = [];

    angular.element('.photo-group').each(function(){
        var object = {};
            $(this).find('.photo').each(function(){
                var key = $(this).attr('name');
                var value = $(this).val();
                object[key] = value;
            });

            arrayOfPhotos.push(object)
            arrayOfArrays.push(arrayOfPhotos)
            console.log(arrayOfArrays)
    });

}
```

**and this is my markup**

```
<div class="photo-group">
    <div class="photo-group-body">
        <div class="initial-photo">
            <div class="row no-padding new-photo">
                <div class="col no-padding">
                    <div class="form-group no-right-padding">
                        <label class="label-control" class="label-control">Label</label>
                        <input type="text" name="photo_label" class="form-control photo">
                        <input type="text" name="image_data" class="form-control photo photo_data">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="initial-photo">
            <div class="row no-padding new-photo">
                <div class="col no-padding">
                    <div class="form-group no-right-padding">
                        <label class="label-control" class="label-control">Label</label>
                        <input type="text" name="photo_label" class="form-control photo">
                        <input type="text" name="image_data" class="form-control photo photo_data">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>

<div class="photo-group">
    <div class="photo-group-body">
        <div class="initial-photo">
            <div class="row no-padding new-photo">
                <div class="col no-padding">
                    <div class="form-group no-right-padding">
                        <label class="label-control" class="label-control">Label</label>
                        <input type="text" name="photo_label" class="form-control photo">
                        <input type="text" name="image_data" class="form-control photo photo_data">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

In my markup I have two `.photo-group` classes.

on the first `.photo-group` class I have four `.photo` class

and on the second `.photo-group` class I have two `.photo` class

so my array should look like this

```
[
   [
     {"photo_label":"value1", "image_data":"value2"},
     {"photo_label":"value3", "image_data":"value4"},
   ],

   [
     {"photo_label":"value4", "image_data":"value5"},
   ]
]`
```

but instead, what I get is only the last objects in each array

```
[
   [
     {"photo_label":"value3", "image_data":"value4"},
   ],

   [
     {"photo_label":"value4", "image_data":"value5"},
   ]
]`
```

Comment: put inside for each ? this one `var arrayOfArrays =[];
    var arrayOfPhotos = [];`

Comment: What if you use ```arrayOfPhotos.push(object)``` in the loop? I am unable to run the code so, just trying.

Answer (score 0):

creat the pushing object inside foreach

```
angular.element('.photo-group').each(function(){

            $(this).find('.photo').each(function(){
                var object = {};
                var key = $(this).attr('name');
                var value = $(this).val();
                object[key] = value;
                arrayOfPhotos.push(object);
            });


            arrayOfArrays.push(arrayOfPhotos);
            console.log(arrayOfArrays);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So after hours of trial and error testing and tracing the flow of the code.. I was able to get what I want.

Here's what I did

```
$scope.saveImages = function(){
    var arrayOfArrays =[];
    angular.element('.photo-group').each(function(){
        var arrayOfPhotos = [];
            $(this).find('.initial-photo').each(function(){
                var object = {};
                    $(this).find('.photo').each(function(){
                        var key = $(this).attr('name');
                        var value = $(this).val();
                        object[key] = value;
                    });
                arrayOfPhotos.push(object)
            });
            arrayOfArrays.push(arrayOfPhotos);
    }); 
}
```

I added another loop to go deep into the child elements and place the  `var arrayOfPhotos = [];` in the first instance of the loop